# Jquery trigger click select

Tags: jquery, woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce and i suspect some jquery code is ran by a click event on an option.

What happens is when clicking on the select box option a hidden input value is populated.

I've tried to simulate triggering the click/onchange event but the hidden input value doesn't change.

```
    $(".variations").find("select[name^=attribute]").val(variable_name).attr('selected',true).parent().trigger('change');
$(".variations").find("select[name^=attribute]").val(variable_name).prop('selected',true);
```

This changes the select option but doesn't trigger the code that is supposed to be added.

How do i solve this?  I've checked it's definitely a click that changes the hidden input values.

Comment: Please make the example in fiddle and paste ur html code

Comment: Try to use this plugin: _https://github.com/Prinzhorn/jquery-inlog_ ... with it you will can see exactly what event you will need to trigger.